# Snapchat like swipe between views in Titanium Alloy

Tags: android, ios, titanium, titanium-alloy

Does anyone know how to incorporate a swipe between views functionality using Titanium Alloy that is similar to this framework https://github.com/cwRichardKim/RKSwipeBetweenViewControllers.

I have searched everywhere and can't seem to find any examples. Are there any or is this not possible in titanium with the current frameworks available?

Comment: I never used Snapchat. Can you explain what is "Snapchat like swipe"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ScrollableView of titanium is your friend here you go

http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.UI.ScrollableView

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow();

var view1 = Ti.UI.createView({ backgroundColor:'#123' });
var view2 = Ti.UI.createView({ backgroundColor:'#246' });
var view3 = Ti.UI.createView({ backgroundColor:'#48b' });

var scrollableView = Ti.UI.createScrollableView({
  views:[view1,view2,view3],
  showPagingControl:true
});

win.add(scrollableView);
win.open();
```

Thanks